# Can't seem to capture values from HTML element in Squarespace codeblock

Tags: javascript, squarespace

I'm working with a Squarespace webpage. There's a calculation page where users enter a numerical value into 'input 1', and another numerical value into 'input 2'. These values are then automatically run through some calculations which then populates a 'input 3'. 
I need to extract the calculated value from input 3, but I just can't seem to do it. 

I added a codeblock with the following code, the aim of which was to extract the value from input 3 (of id `finalResults`) and then render that value in a `p` tag:

```
<p id="value-container"></p>

<script>

  function myScript() {
    const finalResultValue = document.getElementById('finalResults');
    const container = document.getElementById('value-container');
    container.innerText = finalResultValue.innerText;
  }

  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', myScript);
</script>
```

The p tag displays nothing when I save and view the website. I've entered values into input 1 and input 2, which then generates a number that populates input 3, but still nothing is displayed. I also added an event listener to input 3, but that didn't help either.

In this code I am trying to access an element that is **outside the codeblock but within the page I'm working on**

Any ideas on how to fix this? Basically as soon as the user has entered both numbers and generated a result, I want that result to be instantly displayed.